# Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \neq10^{10}$ using a proof by contradiction style epsilon delta.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 \neq10^{10}$ using a proof by contradiction style epsilon delta.

**My Attempt:**

We can show pretty straightforwardly that $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 = \infty$, hence we need to show a contradiction in this function having two limits. By definition

$(1)$ for all $ M_1 > 0$ there exists an $N_1 > 0 $ s.t. $x > N_1 \rightarrow x^2 > M_1$

$(2)$ for all $ \epsilon_2 > 0$ there exists an $N_2 > 0 $ s.t. $x > N_2 \rightarrow |x^2 - 10^{10}| < \epsilon_2$

Let $N = max(N_1, N_2)$. Then for $x > N \rightarrow x^2 > M$. However $M > L + \epsilon_2$ which would make $|x^2 - 10^{10}| > \epsilon_2$. Hence by contridiction, the limit does not hold.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: I think you want $\max(N_1,N_2)$, not $\min$.

Comment: I am not sure this is how it's supposed to be done though. It seems like you are using that a limit is unique, and that the $limit = \inf$. But it doesn't really look like what you are probably supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem when you write “However $M>L+\varepsilon_2$”. Why? I had not mentioned $M$ nor $L$ before. Why is $M$ greater than $L+\varepsilon_2$?

Besides, it is not clear to me that you can use the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2=\infty$.

You can do it as follows. In order to prove that we don't have $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2=10^{10}$, I will take $\varepsilon=1$. Take $M>0$. Now, take some $x$ which is both greater than $M$ and greater than $10^6$. Then$$x>10^6\implies x^2>10^{12}\implies|x^2-10^{10}|\geqslant1.$$So, I have proved that there is a number $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for every $M>0$, there is some $x>M$ such that $|x^2-10^{10}|\geqslant\varepsilon$, or$$(\exists\varepsilon>0)(\forall M>0)(\exists x>M):|x^2-10^{10}|\geqslant\varepsilon,$$which the same thing as asserting that we don't have $\lim_{\to\infty}x^2=10^{10}$.

Comment: Is it $M $ and greater than $10^5$. instead $10^6$? why must it be $10^6$ specifically if I am wrong?

Comment: From the fact that $x$ is greater than $10^5$, all you can deduce is that $x^2>10^{10}$, but you can't deduce that $|x^2-10^{10}|\geqslant1$. That's why I chose $10^6$. There are smalle choces that will also work, such as $10^5+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your proof is correct, although you need to take $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$ so that you can use both (1) and (2).

Also I would use $\Rightarrow$ in place of $\to$, since that is usually meant to denote a limit in these kinds of proofs.

I think you can shorten it just by saying that if $\lim x^2=10^{10}$, given $\epsilon > 0$, we should be able to find $N$ such that $|x^2-10^{10}|<\epsilon$ for all $x>N$, but when $x>10^5+\epsilon$, it is clear that this is false.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to be more clear we could proceed as follows, suppose

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2 =10^{10}$$

that is

$$\forall  \epsilon> 0 \quad \exists N > 0 \quad \forall x > N \quad |x^2 - 10^{10}| < \epsilon$$

but for $x^2 > 10^{10}+\epsilon$ we obtain a contradiction.